# Reference xaml object from another xaml's codebehind?

Tags: xaml, silverlight-4.0, instance, code-behind, object-reference

I have to set a dynamic datapager PageSize depending on the ActualHeight of a grid that "includes" the xaml I am working on. I need to access this Grid from the included XAML's codebehind, and I keep getting "object reference required" errors.

Here is how the grid is defined in the "parent" Main.xaml file :

```
<Grid x:Name="GridContent" MaxHeight="500" MinHeight="400" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
```

And here is how I am trying to access it in my Page.xaml.cs :

```
Grid gridContent = baseProject.Main.GridContent;
```

This returns an "object reference required" error about GridContent.

I also tried creating a public Accessor to GridContent in Main.xaml.cs, but when I call it from Page.xaml.cs, I still get an "object reference required" error, this time about "baseProject.Main.gridContentAccessor.get".

What am I missing? How can I possibly get a hold of the instance of this Grid?

Comment: Actually nevermind, I found a solution that dismisses the need for this height value: since Page.xaml is integrated in this "GridContent" grid, I can just use the ActualHeight of the "UserControl" element of Page.xaml, which logically matches GridContent's ActualHeight.

This does not exactly answer the question (i.e. "how to access an element from another xaml file") since I found an alternative solution, but I just wanted to notify here that my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the VisualTreeHelper functions.
Try something along the lines of a recursive function that calls VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this) until it finds the object you want.

Comment: I apologize in advance if there is a misunderstanding, but I do not believe there is an actual "parent/child" relationship between those two classes. "Page.xaml" is just one of the many pages that is included in the Grid that is defined in "Main.xaml". So my mentionning of Main.xaml as a "parent" was probably more vulgarization than factual.

Comment: Once the xaml is processed and rendered, you can think of all the usercontrols as being "flattened out". The Grid on your main.xaml contains the usercontrol known as page.xaml. So if you keep calling GetParent over and over and runtime, passing in the result of the previous call as the parameter you should eventually get to your desired main.xaml content.

Comment: Indeed I now see what you meant. Though you can also just call the "Parent()" method on any FrameworkElement, which I think is pretty neat! But a bit repetitive in the code.